# Which Spring extension mechanism should I use?

Tags: xml, spring

Lets say I have a set of bean (a,b,c) implementing one interface and a map.

M.xml

```
<bean name="map" class="java.util.HashMap"/>
```

abc.xml

```
<import M.xml>
<bean name="a" class="org.a"/>
<bean name="b" class="org.b"/>
<bean name="c" class="org.c"/>
```

def.xml

```
<import M.xml>
<bean name="d" class="org.d"/>
<bean name="e" class="org.e"/>
<bean name="f" class="org.f"/>
```

I would like a,b,c to be put in the map once the configuration is instantiated. Of course a, b, c should not know about the map. This registration should be included in the configuration using an import because in another scenario, it could be d,e,f, that must be regsitered. Which Spring extension mechanism should I use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same thing as you ever. The good way is to use ***BeanPostProcessor*** and ***ApplicationContextAware*** .

Fristly, Let a, b, c implement a marker interface such as:

```
public interface MappedValue { //leaving blank is ok because this is marker interface }

public a implements MappedValue { ... }
public b implements MappedValue { ... }
public c implements MappedValue { ... }
```

Secondly, Define and add a bean which implements ***BeanPostProcessor*** and ***ApplicationContextAware*** to your application context.

```
public class MapPopulator implements BeanPostProcessor, ApplicationContextAware{

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private String mapbeanName;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public void setMapbeanName(String mapbeanName) {
        this.mapbeanName = mapbeanName;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {

        if( bean instanceof MappedValue){
            Map map = (Map)applicationContext.getBean( mapbeanName );
            map.put( beanName, bean );
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks I could implement what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Autowired`. If you mark a collection with it, it will put all beans of matching interface in this collection. Your "map" bean should be of type `MyMap` below:

```
public class MyMap implements Map {
  @Autowired
  private List<SharedInterface> foundBeans;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    // populate map by inserting objects from foundBeans with appropriate keys
  }
}
```

or alternatively, using original "map" bean and addind a mapBuilder bean of this class:

```
public class MyMapBuilder {
  @Autowired
  private List<SharedInterface> foundBeans;

  @Resource(name="map")
  private Map map;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    // populate map by inserting objects from foundBeans with appropriate keys
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is probably a valid answer as well. However, I can accept only one. I choosed the other one because we are not using autowired for the moment.